# Lucene search query in different file formats

Tags: apache, lucene

I'm using Apache's Lucene 3.0.3 on Windows 7. I'm able to index files successfully given any file extensions (.doc, .ppt, .pdf, .txt, .rtf etc). But, I'm able to search for a word(s) in any spoken human language(Indian/foreign) from only the indexed text document(s) but not from indexed Word/Powerpoint/PDF documents. Why is this? Is it possible for Lucene to do this directly?

Do I need to use a higher version of Lucene? I'm aware of Lucene 4.8.1. Do I need to use that to achieve my task stated above or is not possible for Lucene 3 to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Lucene doesn't interpret content.  It indexes the content you give it and makes it searchable.  If you hand it binary garbage, it will happily index it and make it searchable, it just won't be in searchable via human language.  .doc, .ppt, .pdf, and .rtf formats are not plain-text, and so won't index well by just reading and chucking them directly into lucene.

You need to extract the content from the documents in order to search them meaningfully.  I'd recommend using [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/).